# Is it possible to check DOM.readyState for Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, code-coverage

I want to create a 100% coverage result for my unit tests, unfortunately it's just keep saying that 'if path is not taken' for this case.

```
var state = document.readyState;
if(state === 'interactive' || state === 'complete') {
  runRight();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', runRight(), false);
}
```

I tried out a lot of stuff but still no progress, this is the only problem of my script, does anybody have a proper method for this issue?

Comment: why are you calling `runRight()` in `addEventListener`? what is `if path is not taken"?

Comment: Presence of that method is inessential right now, I just left it there. When I run my unit tests, Istambul gives me this coverage report and tells me the quoted statement.

Comment: how is DOM.readystate related to code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing you want to mock all the methods/variables that do not belong to your application. In your case, you have to mock/eclipse document.readyState and document.addEventListener.

If mocking document object is not your thing, then you may still get decent coverage by changing your code into more unit-testible way:

```
    var initialize = function(state, addListener, cb){
        if(state === 'interactive' || state === 'complete') {
          cb();
        } else {
          addListener('DOMContentLoaded', cb(), false);
        }
     }

     initialize(document.readyState, document.addEventListener, runRight);
```

Then in your unit tests you would test initialize method with different input parameters.

As a side note, 100% UT coverage is often hard to achieve within reasonable effort.